# Join T2 to T1 on T2.x = T1.x if there is a match, else on T2.y = T1.y if no match

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 2 tables: An Events table which contains the teams and the users on those teams who are registered for an event, and a Teams table which contains all teams and their players (independent of Events).

I would like to join Teams onto Events where Teams.user_id = Events.user_id, and then to join any remaining rows in Teams where Teams.team_id = Events.team_id.

So for example, these 2 tables would yield the following result

```
+---------------------------------------+    +-------------------------+
|                 Events                |    |          Teams          |
+----------+---------+---------+--------+    +---------+---------+-----+
| event_id | team_id | user_id |  foo   |    | team_id | user_id | bar |
+----------+---------+---------+--------+    +---------+---------+-----+
|    1     |    1    |    1    |   1    |    |    1    |    1    |  A  |
+----------+---------+---------+--------+    +---------+---------+-----+
|    1     |    1    |    2    |   0    |    |    1    |    2    |  A  |
+----------+---------+---------+--------+    +---------+---------+-----+
|    1     |    2    |   NULL  |  NULL  |    |    2    |    3    |  A  |
+----------+---------+---------+--------+    +---------+---------+-----+
|    1     |    3    |    5    |   0    |    |    2    |    4    |  B  |
+----------+---------+---------+--------+    +---------+---------+-----+
                                             |    3    |    5    |  A  |
                                             +---------+---------+-----+
                                             |    4    |    6    |  A  |
                                             +---------+---------+-----+
```

```
+---------------------------------------------+
|               Expected Result               |
+----------+---------+---------+--------+-----+
| event_id | team_id | user_id |  foo   | bar |
+----------+---------+---------+--------+-----+
|    1     |    1    |    1    |   1    |  A  |
+----------+---------+---------+--------+-----+
|    1     |    1    |    2    |   0    |  A  |
+----------+---------+---------+--------+-----+
|    1     |    2    |    3    |  NULL  |  A  |
+----------+---------+---------+--------+-----+
|    1     |    2    |    4    |  NULL  |  B  |
+----------+---------+---------+--------+-----+
|    1     |    3    |    5    |   0    |  A  |
+----------+---------+---------+--------+-----+
```

I have tried various queries like the following, but most result in the whole roster from a team in Teams being joined onto each user_id in Events where the team_ids match.

```sql
SELECT Events.*, Teams.*
FROM Events
RIGHT JOIN Teams ON CASE
  WHEN Teams.user_id = Events.user_id
  THEN Teams.user_id = Events.user_id
  ELSE Teams.team_id = Events.team_id
END
WHERE Events.event_id = (/* subquery that yields event_id */)

/* or for join */

RIGHT JOIN Teams ON
  (Teams.user_id = Events.user_id AND Teams.team_id = Events.team_id)
  OR Teams.team_id = Events.team_id
/* also */
RIGHT JOIN Teams ON
  (Events.user_id IS NOT NULL AND Teams.user_id = Events.user_id)
  OR (Events.user_id IS NULL AND Teams.team_id = Events.team_id)`
```

**Edit**: Adjusted table to account for duplicate users being joined by using something like `LEFT JOIN Teams ON Teams.user_id = Events.user_id OR Teams.team_id = Events.team_id`.

Comment: Most people find `main table left join optional data` much easier to understand than `optional data right join main table`.

Comment: try ((Teams.user_id = Events.user_id AND Teams.team_id = Events.team_id)
  OR (Teams.user_id is null AND Teams.team_id = Events.team_id))

Comment: @Emanuele I tried that but Teams.user_id will never actually be null so that just gives me results of the first part, `Teams.user_id = Events.user_id AND Teams.team_id = Events.team_id`

Comment: I used Teams.user_id is null not Teams.team_id

Comment: @jarlh The issue with that is that I do not know the team_ids I need beforehand, only the event_id in Events, so I have to join Teams onto Events.

Comment: @Emanuele sorry I've corrected it, what I meant to put is Teams.user_id

Comment: So then, what have you got? In your sample there are null values.

Comment: The null values are in Events.user_id not Teams.user_id. I did try `RIGHT JOIN Teams ON (Events.user_id IS NOT NULL AND Teams.user_id = Events.user_id) OR (Events.user_id IS NULL AND Teams.team_id = Events.team_id)`, but that seems to only join 1 row from Teams onto 1 row from Events.

Comment: Correction: With that query, the remaining team rosters only get joined where there is a null value in Events.user_id, but then it also joins the entire roster onto Events.team_id in that case even if some rows were already joined by their user_id, so I get some user_ids twice with only 1 of each having the right data.

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if this works for your complete dataset. It has worked with your sample data provided as shown in the db fiddle below:

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
CREATE TABLE events (
  `event_id` INTEGER,
  `team_id` INTEGER,
  `user_id` VARCHAR(4),
  `foo` VARCHAR(4)
);

INSERT INTO events
  (`event_id`, `team_id`, `user_id`, `foo`)
VALUES
  ('1', '1', '1', '1'),
  ('1', '2', 'NULL', 'NULL'),
  ('1', '3', '5', '0');
  
  

CREATE TABLE teams (
  `team_id` INTEGER,
  `user_id` INTEGER,
  `bar` VARCHAR(1)
);

INSERT INTO teams
  (`team_id`, `user_id`, `bar`)
VALUES
  ('1', '1', 'A'),
  ('1', '2', 'A'),
  ('2', '3', 'A'),
  ('2', '4', 'B'),
  ('3', '5', 'A'),
  ('4', '6', 'A');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT
    e.event_id,
    e.team_id,
    t.user_id,
    CASE
        WHEN e.user_id <> t.user_id THEN NULL
        ELSE e.foo
    END as foo,
    t.bar
FROM
   events e
INNER JOIN
   teams t ON e.user_id = t.user_id OR t.team_id = e.team_id;
```

| event_id | team_id | user_id | foo | bar |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | A |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | NULL | A |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | NULL | A |
| 1 | 2 | 4 | NULL | B |
| 1 | 3 | 5 | 0 | A |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/erVK75nLDbLtWTJZGZqdnN/1)

Comment: Sorry I know I'm way late for this, I got sidetracked doing other stuff and finally just came back to this.  The problem here is that this causes a team from the Teams table to be joined for every user on that team in the Events table. For example, if you also add user 2 from team 1 to the Events table, then the join query will cause team 1 to be joined *twice*, once on each user from that team. And when used with a GROUP_CONCAT (which I aim to do), then you cannot use something like `GROUP BY t.user_id`. Perhaps I will just have to abandon using GROUP_CONCAT and do that in my JS code.